# Does getting questions closed harm user rating?

Tags: discussion

Lately I've been getting quite a few questions closed. I guess I'm asking about things that are too specific to my situation.

I've had my account blocked because I was in the habit of deleting questions when I found the answers myself. I'm not doing that anymore, but I'm a little concerned my account might be closed again as a result of all the questions getting closed.

Is there any risk here?

Comment: What do you mean by getting your account blocked? You appear to have a good track record on SO in terms of your questions - it's very unlikely you have been question banned.

Comment: I had too many deleted questions so my score got low enough that the system automatically closed my account

Comment: So I guess all of those posts got undeleted at some point?  There is a small risk of getting banned from having a lot of questions closed, but I'd second @BoltClock'saUnicorn's guess that you're nowhere near it at the moment.

Comment: @Ortund: What score? What closing of your account? What rating? The system uses none of these terms with user accounts (well except "reputation score" but I don't think that's what you're referring to). If your account has been restricted in any way the system should tell you exactly what happened to it - you need to use those exact words to describe the state of your account to give us a clearer idea of what you're referring to.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I don't really remember... I logged in one day and was told that my account had been closed. I emailed to get it opened and was told that the deletes had dropped some score to below a certain threshold which is why my account had been automatically closed. Just a few upvotes and accepts on my part was enough to raise my score high enough to reopen my account

Comment: @BilltheLizard: You're saying that Ortund doesn't currently have any deleted questions?

Comment: You have 6 closed questions out of... 110. That's probably not gonna hurt you.

Comment: @DavidRobinson He has some, but it didn't look like enough for a ban.  It sounds like it was though, so I guess his other posts just naturally brought him out of it.

Answer (score 9):

> I've had my account blocked because I was in the habit of deleting questions when I found the answers myself.

Something we've changed fairly recently is the handling of questions that are self-deleted when *no one else has put time into them* - so for instance, a question is posted and doesn't get any answers at all, and is then deleted.

There's a certain unfortunate mentality among some folks that leads them to delete questions as soon as they've been answered - this is incredibly hostile toward the community, and is heavily penalized by the system, but wasn't meant to also hurt folks who just clean up after themselves. I think your experience is evidence that the recent tweaks are doing the right thing finally.

Answer (score 4):

From the canonical [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) (emphasis added)

> All questions are expected to have some value for later visitors too. So if many of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted, **closed**, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality.

While the exact details of the question ban algorithm are secret, question closures do appear to be taken into account.